# PHP Function that returns an array of values of keys

Tags: php, arrays, associative-array

I have an array like this...

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 10651            
            [userid] => 079eb9f4b9eb573f6aec93ce97ed1e7f
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 74315
            [userid] => 1283612836
        )
    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 74315
            [userid] => asydk12893489123
        )
)
```

is there a php function that returns me an array of values of the key `userid` if I make a call like this...

```
func($arr_name, $key_name);
```

Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, but you can make one.

```
function getFromKey($array, $keyName) {
    $return = array();
    foreach ($array as $value) {
        if (isset($value[$keyName]))
            $return[] = $value[$keyName];
    }

    return $return;
}
```